# price to be advised and quoted separately

Tags: grammar, tense, sequence-of-tenses, tense-agreement

> price to be advised and quoted separately

In the sentence above, is the word *quoted* a short form of *to be quoted*?

Should it be **price to be advised and quote separately**?

---

Edit to **add more context**: I saw the sentence on a price calculation form. The form has a list of items with prices. A few items without price have this statement `price to be advised and quoted separately`.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is expressing two distinct thoughts:

> - Price to be advised separately
> - Price to be quoted separately

Just like in mathematics, things that are common to the two clauses ("common factors") can be extracted ("factored") out:

> Price to be [advised and quoted] separately

I would not call this an example of good writing. It is too verbose, and I don't know what "advised" adds to the sentence that isn't conveyed by "quoted." I would write it as **Price quoted separately** and leave it at that.

Comment: Sorry, should have provided more context. I saw the sentence on a price calculation form. The form has a list of items with prices. A few items without price have this statement `price to be advised and quoted separately`. I assume it means it requires a consultation to determine the final price and will be quoted separately? - I'll add this to the OP.

Comment: @FlyingPenguin, thanks for the additional context but it doesn't change any of my answer.

Comment: Thanks! By omitting `to be advised`, does it remove `the need for consultation`?

Comment: @FlyingPenguin, you could say it does, but I'm not convinced in the first place that "price to be advised" means "we must have a consultation." It's a term I'm familiar with—perhaps it is common to say that in the pricing and procurement industry, or perhaps the writer is not being clear.

Comment: It's a standard piece of business terminology, copied from one form to another for decades, so it doesn't have to be good English (whether that means elegant, terse, unambiguous, or something else.)